# Upgrading Linux kernel module without reboot

Tags: linux, kernel

Is there any way to upgrade linux driver module without rebooting the system ?

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible to remove the module and reload it, you are saved. `rmmod module_to_unload && modprobe module_to load`

If it is the network card, don't do that by the network...